# How I can saving in two database tables with Hibernate if the father table contain a serial?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am working in a `Java` web application with `Hibernate 4.3.x` and `postgres 9.4`. I need to save two tables in the same `transaction` in a complex solution that required `serial` columns. The next example is a basic for I can explain my real problem:

This is the data model; a `Object` of `Table2` have many `Objects` of `Table1` and it's very important to insert one `row` in the `Table2` and `many` rows in the `Table1` in a same time, with the reference (`FK`) to `Table2`:

[image]

[The Table1.column_fk is `int` no `serial`, image error]

My problem is I don't know the `Table2.column_pk` value, for this I can't save in `Table1` easily, because I wouldn't request an `query` consult (`Table2 objTable2 = session.createQuery("SELECT t2 from Table2 order by column_pk desc").list().get(0);`) and after add its `column_pk` for each `Table1 objects` (`objTable1_1.setTable2(objTable2); objTable1_2.setTable2(objTable2); ...`). I believe `Hibernate` have easy way for this cases.

For the example, this could be the `Java` simple code:

Table1.java:

```
public class Table1{

    private int columnPk;
    private String columnX;
    private Table2 table2;

    public Table1(String columnX){
        this.columnX = columnX;
    }

    public int getColumnPk() {
        return columnPk;
    }

    public void setColumnPk(int columnPk) {
        this.columnPk = columnPk;
    }

    public String getColumnX() {
        return columnX;
    }

    public void setColumnX(String columnX) {
        this.columnX = columnX;
    }

    public Table2 getTable2() {
        return table2;
    }

    public void setTable2(Table2 table2) {
        this.table2 = table2;
    }

}
```

Table2.java:

```
public class Table2{

    private int columnPk;
    private String columnX;

    public Table2(){
    }

    public int getColumnPk() {
        return columnPk;
    }

    public void setColumnPk(int columnPk) {
        this.columnPk = columnPk;
    }

    public String getColumnX() {
        return columnX;
    }

    public void setColumnX(String columnX) {
        this.columnX = columnX;
    }

}
```

Function with Hibernate:

```
    public void saveAll() throws Exception {
        Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Table2 objTable2 = new Table2();
            List<Table1> listTable1 = new ArrayList<Table1>();
            objTable2.setColumnX("text");
            save(objTable2);
            //In this line, I need collect objTable2 with serial assigned
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                listTable1.add(new Table1("text"));
                //In this line I should add the Table2: listTable1.get(i).setTable2(objTable2);
                //In this line I should to save the objsTable1: save(listTable1.get(i));
            }
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Please, consider that everything else is perfect.

Thank you!